# Latent Semantic Analysis - Co-occurrence of words

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, topic-models, natural-language

Let $A[n\times m]$ represents the term-document matrix, where, $n$ is the number of terms and $m$ is the number of documents. This matrix can be composed into 3 matrices (SVD decomposition) such as,
                         $A = U\times W \times V^T$

Its truncated version can be written as:
$A_k = U_k\times W_k \times V_k^T$

Now the term-term matrix can be written as
$T_k = U_k\times W_k \times W_k^T \times U_k^T$

According to the papers I read this $T_k$ represents the high order co-occurrence information. I understand that this matrix represents the first order co-occurrence but I did not understand how this matrix represents the high-order co-occurrence information.

For me, I think that $T^N_k = U_k\times W_k \times (W_k^T \times U_k^T)^N$ will represents that $N^{th}$ (upto) order co-occurrence.

Could anybody please explain it to me.

Comment: Can you give the reference of the paper you mention?